# Using Eventbrite APIv3, can I retrieve and add the Event Image to the loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, api, eventbrite

This is my code, embeded in a wordpress template page.

```
<?php
include "Eventbrite.php"; 

$authentication_tokens = array('app_key'  => 'XXXX',
                           'user_key' => 'XXXX');

$eb_client = new Eventbrite( $authentication_tokens );

try {
    $events = $eb_client->user_list_events();
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    $events = array();
}

<?= Eventbrite::eventList( $events, 'eventListRow'); ?>
```

which returns:

```
<div class='eb_event_list_item' id='evnt_div_123456789'>
    <span class='eb_event_list_date'>Wed, March 22</span>
    <span class='eb_event_list_time'> 7:00 pm</span>
    <a class='eb_event_list_title' href='https://www.eventbrite.com/e/test-event-tickets-123456789?ref=ebapi'>Test Event</a>
    <span class='eb_event_list_location'>Austin, TX</span>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: @MD.AtiqurRahman So, I'm able to pull over my events from my eventbrite account to my website, but I'm trying to pull an image with each event also. I have an image for each uploaded as the Event Image, on the eventbrite side - just need to know if pulling over the image with the api is possible.

Comment: Ok, as you are using evenbrite API, you should have their documentation. I believe, reading the documentation would solve your concern.

If not, do this: `var_dump($eb_client); exit();` . It'll show you whatever you are receiving from eventbrite. And then you need to sort the data, do some query and so on.

I can help you to do so, if you can show me the result of `var_dump()`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone else, I ended up using the logo upload option on the Eventbrite side when the event is created, and using $evnt->logo :

```
<img src='" . $evnt->logo . "' alt='" . $evnt->title . "'>
```